# Join matrices in Python without numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, matrix

I am using nested arrays as a matrix representation. I created the following function for spliting quadratic matrices with size 2^k into four equal parts (used for Strassen algorithm):

```
import itertools
def splitmat(mat):
    n = len(mat)
    return map( \
        lambda (x,y):map(lambda z:z[y[0]:y[1]],mat[x[0]:x[1]]), \
        itertools.product([(0,n/2),(n/2,n)],repeat=2)
    )
```

Now I'm trying to find an inverse function that joins the four parts back to a full matrix. I could use two nested loops, but may there be any *pythonic* way to achieve this? I would prefer to not use numpy but only builtin modules. Do you have any idea or hint how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inverse operation can be split into 2 simplier operation:

1. concatenate rows(`numpy.vstack`)
2. concatenate columns(`numpy.hstack`)

So, if you have matrix divided into 4 submatrix:

```
M = |m1|m2| 
    |m3|m4|
```

then  `M = hstack(vstack(m1, m2), vstack(m3, m4)`.

This operations can be code like this:

```
import itertools
import math

# iterators
def ihstack(*matrixes):
    return map(lambda rows: itertools.chain(*rows), zip(*matrixes))

def ivstack(*matrixes):
    return itertools.chain(*matrixes)

# main function
def squarejoin(*matrixes):
    size = int(math.sqrt(len(matrixes)))
    assert size ** 2 == len(matrixes), 'Incorrect number of matrices'
    return _matrixjoin(matrixes, size, size)

def _matrixjoin(matrixes, hsize, vsize):
    print(matrixes, hsize, vsize)
    return ivstack(*(ihstack(*itertools.islice(matrixes, i*hsize, (i+1)*hsize)) for i in range(vsize)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have an example program where a 2 loops implementation works and is crystal clear in its intent, a 1 loop implementation works and is, imho, slightly less clear and eventually a 0 (explicit, btw) loops implementation that, alas, is buggy.

My vote goes to the two loops... further, I'd like to be shown what's wrong with my 0 loops attempt

### Code

```
import itertools

def pm(m):
    for row in m: print row

mat = []
n = 8
for i in range(n):
    mat.append(range(i*n, i*n+n))

# this is shorthand for your splitmat function
res = map(lambda (x,y):
          map(lambda z:z[y[0]:y[1]],mat[x[0]:x[1]]),
          itertools.product([(0,n/2),(n/2,n)],repeat=2))
pm(res)

print "\n2 cycles"
mat = []
for i, j in ((0,1),(2,3)):
    for a, b in zip(res[i],res[j]):
        mat.append(a+b)
pm(mat)

print "\n1 cycle"
mat = []
for i, j in ((0,1),(2,3)):
    map(lambda x: mat.append(x[0]+x[1]), zip(res[i],res[j]))
pm(mat)

print "\n0 cycles"
mat =  map(lambda i_j: 
       map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], zip(res[i_j[0]],res[i_j[1]])), ((0,1),(2,3)))
pm(mat)
```

### Output

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [8, 9, 10, 11], [16, 17, 18, 19], [24, 25, 26, 27]]
[[4, 5, 6, 7], [12, 13, 14, 15], [20, 21, 22, 23], [28, 29, 30, 31]]
[[32, 33, 34, 35], [40, 41, 42, 43], [48, 49, 50, 51], [56, 57, 58, 59]]
[[36, 37, 38, 39], [44, 45, 46, 47], [52, 53, 54, 55], [60, 61, 62, 63]]

2 cicli
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
[32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
[40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47]
[48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]
[56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]

1 ciclo
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
[32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
[40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47]
[48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]
[56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]

0 cicli
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]]
[[32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39], [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47], [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55], [56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]]
```